# Inverted lat lon on drawn polygons in Openlayers 3

Tags: geoserver, polygon, openlayers, coordinates, wfs-t

I am working on a map in openlayers 3 with geoserver I display the layers as WFS and I added the draw and modify interactions, but when I save the drawn polygons the coordinates of the newly drawn polygon are inverted.

Here is my drawing code:

```
var draw;
var formatwfs = new ol.format.WFS();
function addInteraction() {
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            features: features,
            type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon')
            });
    // when a new feature has been drawn...
    draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        feature.set('the_geom', event.feature.getGeometry());
        var node = formatwfs.writeTransaction([feature], null, null, {
                        gmlOptions: {srsName: "EPSG:4326"},
                        featureNS: "My_Name_Space",
                        featureType: "My_Name_Space:My_Layer"
                    });
         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                    data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),
                    contentType: 'text/xml',
                    error: function(e) {
                            var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
                            alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer.<br><br>'
                                + errorMsg);
                            },
                        context: this
                    });

                });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
```

Every Polygon I draw has its vertices coordinates inverted and so it gets into another location.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are using an EPSG code of `http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326` instead of `epsg:4326` so that the X/Y lat/Lon mapping is fixed rather than variable as it is with `epsg:4326`. Then make sure you are encoding the geometries that you send in the same order as you have told GeoServer to expect them. See the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/webadmin.html#gml) for a longer discussion.

**UPDATE**

To clarify EPSG:4326 means different things in different versions of WFS, I made the same request to a local GeoServer using the 3 WFS protocols and these are the results of the first point:

```
wfs 1.0 -75.70742,38.557476
wfs 1.1 38.557476 -75.70742
Wfs 2.0 38.557476 -75.70742
```

As you can see for WFS 1.0 the order is lon/lat and for 1.1 and 2.0 the order is lat/lon. Since you don't specify which version you want to use the server and the client are free to pick whichever one they fancy (but probably 2.0).

You need to examine the data being sent to GeoServer and pick the version that is most likely to match the order of your coordinates as it appears that the OpenLayers WFS client code isn't smart enough to do this for you.

Comment: I modified it in the gmlOptions in the writeTransaction function but it's still not working

Comment: http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326 - This formats the geographic coordinates in longitude/latitude (x/y) order. This format is the default GML 2 SRS convention. Now make sure you send in that order

Comment: I am confused here, I changed the srsName value to http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326 in the gmlOptions, I changed it too in the projection of the map. is there anywhere else I need to change it, and how please ?

Comment: That is fine - all you need to do is make sure you send the geometry in X/Y Lon/Lat order too otherwise it will be inverted.

Comment: @iant, The short form EPSG:xxxx is fixed and always easting-nothing or lon-lat. Thus it behaves in the same way than WFS 1.0.0 version.

Comment: @user30184 I think it changes between 1.0, 1.1 &  2.0

Comment: Tried to test with http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getfeature&typenames=topp:states&srsname=epsg:4326&count=1 but the server at Boundless is jammed. I expect lon-lat coordinates.

Comment: I added this code to check the coordinates of the newly drawn polygons 

     var formatwkt = new ol.format.WKT();
     var wkt = formatwkt.writeGeometry(event.feature.getGeometry());
     alert(wkt);

the result is lon/lat, so I guess the problem is still in that writeTransact even if I changed its srsName to the one from opengis

Comment: Finally it worked, I had to take off the srsName from gmlOptions and let the default one and that's it

Comment: Changing your gmlOptions to `gmlOptions: {srsName: "CRS:84"}` is the fastest way to fix this. It is the same as "EPSG:4326", but with the opposite axis orientation.